# Loading Multiple Image From server in android Give VM Buget out of memory?

Tags: android

I am using lazy loader example but my application give following error in Logcat.

```
12-14 15:27:55.987: E/dalvikvm-heap(27566): 2457600-byte external allocation too large for this process.

12-14 15:27:55.992: E/(27566): VM won't let us allocate 2457600 bytes

12-14 15:27:55.992: D/skia(27566): --- decoder->decode returned false
```

I am use Imageloader class in that write

```
  private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
            try {
                //decode image size
                BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                o.inPurgeable = true; // Tell to garbage collector that whether it needs free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
                o.inTempStorage = new byte[32 * 1024];
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

                //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
                final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
                int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
                int scale=1;
                while(true){
                    if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                        break;
                    width_tmp/=2;
                    height_tmp/=2;



                      scale*=2; 


                }

                //decode with inSampleSize
                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o2.inPurgeable = true; // Tell to garbage collector that whether it needs free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
                o2.inTempStorage = new byte[32 * 1024];
                o2.inSampleSize=scale;
                Bitmap bitmap1=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
              //  System.out.println("width : "+bitmap1.getWidth()+ " height : "+bitmap1.getHeight());
           /*     if(bitmap1.getHeight()>=bitmap1.getWidth())
                {

                    bitmap1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap1, bitmap1.getHeight(),bitmap1.getWidth(), true);
                }else{
                    //bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, (int) height2,width, true);
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

                    matrix.postRotate(270);
                    bitmap1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap1 , 0, 0, bitmap1 .getWidth(), bitmap1 .getHeight(), matrix, true);

                }*/
                return bitmap1;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
            return null;
        }
```

but i use sacle =scale*1 because i want HD image in that use scale-scale*2 then my image like blur..

then what i do?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android-query/ use this library for loading the images

Comment: Where did you set `o.inJustDecodeBounds = false;`

Comment: I try but no solv...i need that

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use the library [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) It is simpler than Android-Universal-Image-Loader but just as powerful.

Comment: Just download the file. Jar and configure the "build path" and then follow the tutorial in the link there is very easy.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to do all this . try this library . this is awesome .
[Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: just read on github . its so simple . if you find any problem ask me.

Comment: nitesh ...this project is not import

Comment: it has a jar only . you need to import that only in your lib. just go to the quick set up on that page.